# internal code representation in java and groovy

Tags: java, groovy

What does java use to represent the code internally?

As far as I understand it builds a tree - as it has `Compiler Tree API` but at the same time it seems not be the same as `Abstract Syntax Tree` that `Groovy` builds and that can be modified via AST transformations. (code in `Clojure` supposed to be represented as is I think)

What is the difference between trees of `Java` and tree of `Groovy`? Why does `Groovy` allows to modify it out of box, while `Java` doesn't?

Comment: It is different implementation of same AST pattern. Can you ask more specific question?

Comment: @talex made more specific. Though it is not a specific question originally

Comment: I would suggest taking some online course or tutorial of learning compiler techniques. That would make it much easier to describe your problem. Java, the interpreter does not represent the code as a tree. the compiler does until it is finished parsing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Abstract Syntax Tree of different languages are usually not compatible. This is the case because the AST represents the code that has been written in the respective language. That means you could traverse the tree and format it to code with identical syntax again (i.e. the whitespaces will differ, the rest is the same). However they cannot be compatible, because the languages have different constructs. For example Groovy has closures which is not the case for Java. You can usually find a mapping to different concepts that will be equivalent, but that's not the point of an AST.

The reason AST transformations are a part of Groovy whereas they are not part of Java is the same closures are part of Groovy but not of Java: different design decisions. Java was designed to be simple. Easy to get into and easy to read albeit often verbose. Groovy had a different focus. The syntax is more concise and things like domain specific languages are desired.

If you are more interested in the internals of compilers I recommend the ["Dragon Book"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321486811). It's as far as I know the standard you read in academics (I read it when I was studying).

Comment: AST is temporal structure during phases of compilation - has limited life. Long living is final *.class files with JVM code

Comment: Java Lombok project uses kind of AST operation, with far similarity to groovy

Comment: You're right, Lombok does that for Java, never implemented my own AST transformation there though.